# How can I Property-based Test a Function that takes a list of functions?

Tags: f#, property-based-testing

How can I Property-based Test a Function that takes a list of functions?

Take the following function:

```
let handleAll handlers item =
    handlers |> List.collect(fun handler -> handler item)
```

Additional context is as follows:

```
let handleAll handlers item =
    handlers |> List.collect(fun handler -> handler item)

let handlers = [
    handleShipping
    handleRoyalty
    handleCommission
    handleVideo
    handleEmail]

(*Client*)
let result = (handlers , Book) ||> handleAll
```

I tried the following test and then realized that none of my predefined functions get used (obviously) because arbitrary functions are being generated at run-time:

Example:

```
   [handleShipping
    handleRoyalty
    handleCommission
    handleVideo
    handleEmail]
```

My property test is the following:

```
(*Property Tests*)
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(MaxTest = 1000, QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``handleAll always returns elements for at least (1) handler`` () =

    (Arb.generate<(Item -> Command list) list> 
    |> Gen.filter(List.isEmpty >> not) , Arb.generate<Item>)
    ||>Gen.map2(fun handlers item -> handlers , item)
    |> Arb.fromGen
    |> Prop.forAll 
    <| fun (handlers , item) ->
     (handlers , item) 
     ||> handleAll
     |> List.isEmpty |> not
```

Is the *handleAll* function Property-based testable?

Comment: Why would you want to test `handleAll`?

Comment: I'm asking if I should...

Comment: Sorry to split hairs, but until now, you're not. You have *how* in your title, and you're asking if the test you've already written makes sense.